# Does the quality of a microphone affect the frequency and intensity(dB) of the sound it can pick up?

Tags: structural-engineering

Does the quality of a microphone affect the frequency and intensity(dB) of the sound it can pick up?

Do all microphones pick up sound as it is in real life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fidelity of sound reproduction is one of the characteristics that varies from microphone to microphone, and it's considered better to have better fidelity.

So, by extension, no, not all microphones are alike in this regard.

Comment: What level should the fidelity of the microphone be, for it to be able to  pick up sound as it is in real life?

Comment: "Pick up sound as it is in real life" either means perfect, and there are no perfect microphones, or it means "pick up sounds good enough to match **my opinion** of real life" -- and the "my opinion" apart varies by person.  So the answer is either "none" or "you have to experiment on your own".

Answer (score 1):

TimWescott is right: not all microphones are alike in their output level and frequency response. Microphones with good frequency response are expensive in rough proportion to their bandwidth. In the recording industry, it is common to choose a specific microphone brand and type for recording a specific instrument or voice because its response matches the output of the source.

Comment: Which type of microphones pick up sound as it is in real life?

Comment: the least expensive mics with best high frequency response are *electret condenser* microphones.